# XSLT code to select different attribute based on value

Tags: xslt, mapping

Can you please advise on the issue

I need to select different attribute xsi:type based on field accountNumber value

sample target structure

```
<paymentOrder xsi:type="XXXX">
<creditAccount>
<accountNumber>XXXXTBXXXXXXXXXXX</accountNumber>
<creditAccount>
```

I need to select different attribute for PaymentOrder node based on accountNumber value

If accountNumber contains value TB, I need to select attribute xsi:type="TransferWithinBank"
otherwise select attribute xsi:type="TransferToOtherBank"

Please advise how to achieve this ?

Varun

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Note that `xsi:type` is an attribute, not a namespace.

Comment: Thansk Mike for the comment and correcting me on the namespace/attribute, I have updated the query.

Comment: Still no [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

it will set the attribute values as per your requirement. (hope you have included `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` in your source as well as xsl)

```
<xsl:template match="paymentOrder">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(//accountNumber, 'TB')">
          <xsl:text>TransferWithinBank</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>TransferToOtherBank</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<paymentOrder xsi:type="TransferWithinBank">
   <creditAccount>
      <accountNumber>XXXXTBXXXXXXXXXXX</accountNumber>
   </creditAccount>
</paymentOrder>
```

Comment: when I test the standalone mapping, it works. but when I import it in my integration tool and run it, it fails with error "Required attribute 'test' is missing."

Comment: When I test with multiple payments scenario, I am facing the issue as "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("GE25TB123", "GE25TB456"),

Comment: @varun does "multiple payments scenario" means multiple `accountNumber` in a single `paymentOrder` ?

Comment: it is multiple payment orders in a single request, I have shared sample expected output above.